# "non-text" in multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

I am trying to add a recipe in a multi-column table. Something like so:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
    Some text  &  More text.\\ 

    \multicolumn{2}{c} 
    {\begin{recipe}{Lemonade, version} {1 liter}{} \end{recipe}} \\ 

\end{tabular}
```

However when trying to compile this, TextStudio throws a number of errors. Plain text compiles without any problems.

Is the desired table even possible in LaTeX? All examples I've seen only handle plain text. If it is, how do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Much better after change, now after I get a "File ended while scanning multicolumn..." error.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
    Some text  &  More text.\\    
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexp12cm+2\tabcolsep}{\begin{recipe}{Lemonade, version} {1 liter}{} text & instructions \end{recipe}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

I'm not experienced with TeX (obviously) and examples with the error message only give suggestions of other code. I can't see what's wrong in the first place. Anyone with a more explicit explanation of what I'm doing wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any information, but I would guess `recipie` is a display environment so can not be in a `c` column (which is single line like `\mbox`) replace `c` by `p{\dimexp12cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}`  (or without the `+\arrayrulewidth` if you have not loaded the `array` package.